# What is the name of this modified Gaussian?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, terminology, truncated-normal-distribution

I am reading a paper that defines

$$ \mathcal{T}(x, \mu, \sigma) = A \cdot x \cdot \exp \left \{ - \left[ \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma} + \frac{\sigma}{2 \mu} \right]^2 \right \}.$$

It is introduced in order to have a Gaussian that goes to zero at $x=0$. It says that $A$ has to be chosen such that $\mathcal{T}$ is "unimodular". I am not sure how to calculate $\mathcal T$ because I am unsure how to find $A$. So my questions are: how can I find $A$, and is there a name for $\mathcal T$?

**Edit**: I am assuming that perhaps by unimodular they mean integrates to equal one. In which case,

$$A^{-1} = \int_x x \cdot \exp \left \{ - \left[ \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma} + \frac{\sigma}{2 \mu} \right]^2 \right \} \text{dx}.$$
Anyone agree...?

Comment: Is a $1/2$ factor missing in the exponential or not?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos I have copied it exactly as it is written

Comment: I should add however that $\sigma$ is not a real standard deviation - this is an ad-hoc function that is supposed to resemble a Gaussian, so the $\sigma$ can just expand arbitrarily to incorporate any missing factor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, set $\sigma\equiv \sqrt{2}\cdot v$, and you get

$$\left[ \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma} + \frac{\sigma}{2 \mu} \right]^2=\frac 12\left[ \frac{x-\mu}{v} + \frac{v}{\mu} \right]^2 = \frac 12\left[ \frac{x-(\mu-(v^2/\mu))}{v}  \right]^2$$

and set $$\tilde \mu \equiv\mu-(v^2/\mu)$$.

This corresponds to a Gaussian random variable with variance $v$ and mean $\tilde \mu$.

So we can write, denoting $\phi()$ the standard Gaussian density

$$\mathcal{T}(x, \mu, \sigma) = A \sqrt{2\pi}\cdot x \cdot \phi\left((x-\tilde \mu)/v\right)$$

If $\mathcal{T}(x, \mu, \sigma)$ is supposed to represent a density, then indeed

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}A \sqrt{2\pi}\cdot x \cdot \phi\left((x-\tilde \mu)/v\right)dx = 1 \implies A \sqrt{2\pi}\cdot E(X) = 1$$

$$\implies A = \frac {1}{\tilde \mu\cdot\sqrt{2\pi}}$$

etc